# menu not displayed after creating new menu in joomla

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla-template

I am new to joomla . I have tried to create a new menu at the top . After creating and adding articles , I am not able to display it on the page .  But when I " Atomic " to its default themes it displays the menu items I have added . Please help me out since no other themes displaying the menu and its items !

Answer (score 1):

The very basic way to display menu in joomla. Create New menu in joomla menu manager then go the extensions -> Module Manager -> New Module -> Select Menu Type from radio options -> Then move to Next and then you can use the menu which you created in module parameter by selecting from menu name and assign a position and enabled that menu..

IN the Themplate you have to call the menu like

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu position which you assign while creating menu"/>
```

Hopefully this will help You.

Comment: Thanks Pramod. But in which file I need to add that line ?

Comment: Have you create your own template in joomla or using any other default template....?

Comment: Please let me know about these 1.Joomla version 2.Default Template name which you are using. 3. Position assigned to that menu..

Answer (score 0):

Try different positions in the module settings for the menu. Some templates have fixed height of the positions, wich means that if you put two modules at the same position one of them won't show.